# jQuery on(click) doesn't work but on(hover) does

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

After initialize js I create new `<div>` element with close class and `on("click")` function doesn't work.

```
$(document).on('click', '.post-close', function () {
        alert("hello");
});
```

but `on('hover')` work perfectly.

```
$(document).on('hover', '.post-close', function () {
        alert("hello");
});
```

but I need to make it work on click.

Comment: I think you posted the same code twice.

Comment: Also, is it `on(hover)` or `live(hover)`?

Comment: I would also try running your code through the W3C validator, sometimes DOM issues can cause problems with javascript events. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/2MdRR/

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're not preventing the default behaviour of the browser. Pass `e` into your handler and then use `e.preventDefault()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.post-close', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("hello");
});
```

### Edit

Also, bind the handler before creating the new `<div>`

Comment: do you get any errors in the console or anything? What if you console.log() instead of alert?

Answer (score 1):

why not use something like

```
$('.post-close').click(function(){
   //do something
});
```

If the element was added dynamically use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.post-close', function(){
   //do something
});
```

edit:
like danWellman said, you can add the preventDefault IF you want to make sure no other code is executed. otherwise use the code above.

edit2:
changed the .live to .on

Comment: `.live();` is deprecated, use `.on();` instead:

"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Comment: @GeertJaminon: thanks for the update. Guess I'm a bit behind on my jquery versions.

Comment: @Ruben ~ not only that, actually, but you posted what is essentially the same code. I think what you wanted to share was that for **dynamically added** elements, you want to use the **delegate** flavor of `.on()`. That has a syntax of `container.on(eventtype, selector, handler)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but I've had a exactly same problem (element created dynamically, hover works, but click doesn't) and found solution.
I hope this post helps someone.

In my case, I found ui-selectable is used for parent element and that was preventing from click event propagate to the document.

So I added a selector of the button element to ui-selectable's 'cancel' option and problem solved.

If you have a similar probrem, check this

- Try turn of libraries for parent element
- You're not using stopPropagation() in parent element ?